# understanding sql query

Tags: sql

Specifically, I would like to know what the trailing email at the end of the first line does. Is this essentially the same thing as SELECT columnname 'AS' email? But, just missing the 'AS'?

```
select distinct initcap(email1) email
from fin_jobs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's just an alias. AS is optional I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It is an alias - it gives a name to the returned column. `AS` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, below queries are the same:

```
select distinct initcap(email1) email
from fin_jobs

select distinct initcap(email1) as email
from fin_jobs

select distinct initcap(email1) as "email"
from fin_jobs

select distinct initcap(email1) "email"
from fin_jobs
```

Keyword `as` is optional for aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

You are no required to put the `as` keyword for aliases

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as with an AS, the AS is optional.

SQL-92 syntax of a select list:

```
<select list> ::=
                <asterisk>
              | <select sublist> [ { <comma> <select sublist> }... ]

         <select sublist> ::=
                <derived column>
              | <qualifier> <period> <asterisk>

         <derived column> ::= <value expression> [ <as clause> ]

         <as clause> ::= [ AS ] <column name>
```

Section 7.9 of the SQL-92 specification.